# How to Git Pull and Display Status Every Second

Tags: git, pull

I’d like to `git pull` and display the status of the of it displayed per line every second with the speed of the download as well. The behavior is just like doing a ping of a certain website and it displays how fast your ping is every second every line.

Comment: git pulls are usually very fast. What is the use case here?

Comment: do u mean multiple pulls every second... or a single pull with status displayed till pull is complete... like how yum does.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous i’d like to see how much my pull is being downloaded every second in kbps. I’m pulling around 5gb worth of data

Comment: @leoOrion a single pull with status displayed until it completes

Answer (score 1):

Try first to see what a [`git fetch --progress`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---progress) would report (since a pull is a fetch plus a merge)

You can also activate `GIT_TRACE2_PERF`

```
export GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1
git pull
```